# How can I set a QTableView's current cell's background colour?

Tags: qt, pyqt

Recently I'm writing a program using Qt(PyQt)'s QTableView. 
But I find that the current cell/index (the focused one, which surrounded by a broken line) has same background colour to other selected cells.

Is there any way to make the current cell stand out? I'm using the Qt Designer to set the stylesheet, but I can't find useful style.

This is my first question here, if I made any mistake, please tell me. Thank you.
Also please excuse my poor English.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a specific reason why you are using QTableView? [QTableWidget](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qtablewidget.html), which is the simple implemented QTableView, lets you achieve the desired effect easily.

1) Query QTableWidget for it's [current item](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qtablewidget.html#currentItem).

2) call [QTablewidgetitem::setBackGround](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qtablewidgetitem.html#setBackground) on it(maybe also foreground)

Comment: Thanks very much for the clue. I think there should be a way in delegate to do setBackGround for model/view. Trying to find it now

Answer (score 0):

For to change the background color of any cell within a QTableView you need to return the color (e.g. as QVariant(QColor(red))) from your data() method of your model class, but only for calls with role parameter set to Qt::BackgroundColorRole.

There is another role Qt::BackgroundRole which is working for me too (in Qt4).